# 1D Convolution Maths

Tags: conv-neural-network

I would like to understand the maths behind 1d Convolution networks.

I have a model which I have shaped my input dimension to be (:, 36, 1).

Now if I have my first layer with a Kernel of 3 then I believe I get 36 - 3 + 1 or 34 features for each filter. Am I then pooling the features for each filter? So does my pooling need to be less than or equal to 34, as I can't pool more features then I create?

On my next layer, with say 100 filters from the previous layer. If I have a pool size of say 6. Do I then have 6 sets of pooled data (using the same padding) across 100 filters giving a new input size of 600?

I can then use the same logic to apply forward and increase my kernels or pooling accordingly.